# Firefox per-tab image block

Tags: gratis, images, firefox

When opening web pages in Firefox, I usually want images to show, but sometimes I want a particular tab to NOT display images, because of reasons like slowness/annoyance/privacy.

Is there an extension or user script for that?

Requirements:

- Push a button (or shortcut) to hide images of a particular tab (or at least prevent them from loading)
- Other tabs must continue to show images as normal
- Works on recent Firefox
- Supports Wikipedia, Facebook, and as many websites as possible
- Free

I tried [Images Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/reviews/), it does not work on Wikipedia because of [a Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1196784).

Comment: You can configure [imglikeopera](http://superuser.com/a/933506/423702) to do what you want. It seems to be an abandoned project (not updated since 2013) but it works *almost* perfectly in my FF 38.x. However, new reviews suggest that it doesn't work for FF 40.x. but you can at least try it. Don't forget to follow the advice [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/reviews/710898/).

Comment: So if you enable this for a tab, and in that same tab you navigate to a different site, it should keep being enabled, right? (i.e., it’s not for the currently shown page/site, but for the tab itself)

Comment: unor: As soon as I navigate to a different site, any behaviour is acceptable: Keep blocking, or stop blocking. I will accept either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seek is the [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) extension called [Tab Permissions](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-permissions) by [Nag. Matsui](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/user/nag-matsui/).

It does exactly what you want:

- You can push a toolbar button to hide [images](/questions/tagged/images) of a particular tab (middle icons below):

  [image: toolbar buttons]
- Other tabs will continue to show images as normal
- Works on recent versions of Firefox
- Supports all websites
- Is completely free (gratis)

It can also be used to toggle javascript, redirects, plug-ins, and frames on any tab.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/) For that.

> Allows quick enable and disable of Java, Javascript, Cookies, Image
>   Animations, Flash, Silverlight, Images, Stylesheets and Proxy from the
>   Toolbar. This is great for increasing security or decreasing
>   bandwidth.

Comment: But this is not per tab, is it?

Comment: You could use [ImgLikeOpera](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/) for that. In this add on you can set different policy for each tab.

Comment: @4mohit: Then would you mind deleting this answer and creating an answer detaling how ImgLikeOpera solves the question? Thanks a lot! :-)